# Why Is Video Streaming Continued Although Node Server Is Closed

Tags: node.js, websocket, video-streaming, webrtc, ports

The video streaming is starting after WebRTC clients exchanged messages with each other. The messages operation is coninued on node server which uses 1337 port and web socket. Video streaming is continued  after  i closed the server on 1337 port. Why ? Which ports are used by webrtc clients. The node server uses one port(1337). How can i learn or control or change these ports which are used by web rtc server and clients?

Answer (score 0):

The Node.js server is only used for session start up and tear down. So, once a session is started(unless media or networking is changed) it will continue until one of the peers end it. Remember, WebRTC is a peer to peer connection.

Once the needed Ice Candidates and SDP information is exchanged for the Peer connection then there is no longer a need for the signalling server(barring any unforeseen network/media changes). One of the peers in the session(the peerconnection itself) would have to end the session and stop streaming.

Edit:

1. For Chrome, by default, the media is muxed on the same port(only one media port is used). In FireFox, I believe that audio and video use separate ports...unless it has been changed in a recent update.
2. You cannot specify media ports in the WebRTC client and still guarantee a media connection can be made(not in any browser implementation, you may be able to do this with the native API). You could modify the ports in the SDP but that would break NAT traversal for the media.
3. The signalling server has nothing to do with what media ports are used by the clients.
4. You most definitely cannot modify the media stream at all after the signalling server is offline as there is no way to exchange media set up information(ports, media type, stream ID, etc..)

I foresee two ways of controlling the media ports in the current javascript APIs:

1. You would have to control the ICE server(s) and what ports they are allowed to try and set up for NAT traversal(STUN and TURN). This would be done server side and cannot be done by the WebRTC(Client side) part of the system. So, you cannot do it simply in WebRTC alone, only by manipulating how the ICE servers gather candidates.
2. Another, very unlikely and almost unmentionable case, is if you knew for a fact what ports are available for NAT traversal(set up port forwarding or something on both peer ends), they you could modify the media port in the SDP before setting it locally and sending it to the peer. You would not need ICE servers in that case.

[Here is a deeper discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/PTPDF4D8m2A) about port allocation for the media

Comment: Can we change port numbers which are used when video stream is continued!

Comment: @MertÖzoğul What do you mean? The Port for the signalling or the port for the media?

Comment: Ports for media stream.

Comment: How many  Ports are used while video stream is continuing.and can we change it?port?port range?

Comment: @MertÖzoğul, it all depends on what is in the SDP. NAT traversal is the main issue here. If you solve that while knowing what ports are available for both sides of the connection, then you could modify the media ports in the SDP.

Comment: My real problem or my main purpose is right distributing. Namely web RTC project use other application's ports. So that other application doesn't work after webrtc video stream is started. Only if i restart my pc and then other application can work. So that i want to change or control webrtc ports. These ports (Video Stream Ports) are used in sdp as you said.@BenjaminTrent.

Comment: @MertÖzoğul,I have the same  problem too.

Comment: Webrtc blocked my applet application when video stream is continuing.

Comment: @MertÖzoğul If you control the ICE servers, then you can control the ports. The main issue is that ICE candidates are grabbed for NAT traversal and those ports are determined by a negotiation between the ICE client and the server. Since you cannot modify the client, you will have to control the ICE server.

Comment: According to  your description other problems will be occurred after i changed this ports number. Because i can't know suitable port number. Do you have any  suggestions for this problem ?

Comment: @MertÖzoğul, have you even read my answer? I give two possible solutions for the JavaScript APIs. Native APIs are a different story as you can specify media ports there.

Comment: @MertÖzoğul, you have to control the Ice Candidates and how they are gathered(from the ICE server). For the browser implementations, they auto-allocate ports(so, if you launch your applet first, it should work). There is no current option to set port ranges in the available JavaScript APIs. I say all of this in my answer...